# Turn span into link without Event Listener

Tags: javascript

I have a menu containing spans and each span must turn into a link (href). The span contains text from an array of strings and the link will be the string in lowercase (+ .aspx).

**Example**:

```
menuItems = ["Home", "Help", "FAQ", "Login"] //Will turn into 4 links
```

I don't want to use Event Listener (onclick) because i want the link to be explicitly in HTML (search engine friendly).

**My suggestion**:

The simplest way i see it is creating the custom `<a>` element and inserting the `span.outerHTML` inside it, but i was wondering if someone have another suggestion.

```
a.innerHTML = span.outerHTML
```

**EDIT**: What are the downsides/upsides of using `<a>` instead of `<span>`? Does `<span>` accept same attributes as `<a>` (except *href*)?

Comment: Why don't you replace `span` with `a`?

Comment: If you want the links to be SEO, then have the links as links.

Comment: Yes that's the obvious solution, i was wondering when it must be a span what would be the best procedure. Always turn into `<a>`? Does `<a>` support the same attributes as `<span>` plus "href"?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far!

Comment: You can always have `<a href="#"><span>Text</span></a>` if you really need to have your spans when the page loads up (i'm not sure about SEO on this but I hardly think it matters)

Comment: Yes that is the method i suggested on my post, i would like to know alternate (simpler) ways or if it is good procedure to use `<a>` instead of `<span>`(upsides/downsides). I've edited the question.

Comment: Alright then SEO dictates you use the semantic tags, when making a navigation menu, you'll have to use `<nav>` as the parent element and `<a>` as link elements with `href` specifying the links, this is the best way to allow for search engines to crawl through your website and it will give you better referencing on google for example. `<span>` is not supposed to be used for links.

Comment: Summuarized the comments in a response

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `<a>` for links, it will help the bots understand the architecture of your page will also provide some advantages afterwards.

SEO-related specifications dictate that you use *semantic tags* such as `<figure> (for images)` to help your website gain ranks.
In your case, you're looking for a navigation menu which should look something like this:

```
   <nav class="headerNav">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <a href="#">Link 2</a>
       <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        ...
   </nav>
```

You can then apply the styles you want with `nav.headerNav` or `nav.headerNav a`.
This will let bots (like google's crawler) that this is a navigation menu and it will follow all the links.

`<span>` may support the `href` element (not on all browsers i beleive) but it's main purpose is not to be used as a link, it's used to *emphasise text* or **make it bold** or colored, mostly ***inline*** editing.